# Ek gaan or Ek sal

Tags: grammar

I know 'Ek sal' means I will. Does Ek gaan mean I will too?

Ek gaan dit beslis nie so aanvaar nie en ek is besig om regshulp in te win.

Comment: I would expect that there is a better place to ask this question than Linguistics. But even if there isn't, you should at least mention which language it's about. (I am guessing some form of Frisian?)

Comment: @Hans Adler: Afrikaans.

Comment: @reinierpost: I see, so it's the *other* language that's right between Dutch and English. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

I don't speak Afrikaans, but Dutch uses the verb *gaan* in the same sense, particularly in Flanders; this use was borrowed, no doubt, from French, which uses *vais* in the same way:

French:

- *Je vais voir* (I'll see)

Dutch:

- *Ik ga zien*                            (I'll see; in Flanders)
- *Ik ga kijken*                          (I'll have a look; in the Netherlands)
- *Ik ga hier beslist niet mee akkoord*   (I will certainly not agree to this)

Comment: Nice answer. In French we actually say "je suis d'accord". "Je vais d'accord" is argot.

Comment: The use of 'gaan' in Dutch is rather subtle as well. For instance, I would never translate 'Ek gaan dit beslis nie so aanvaar nie', as 'Ik ga dit zo beslist niet accepteren', while 'ik zal dit zo beslist niet accepteren', 'ik ga hier beslist niet mee akkoord' and 'ik ga dit zeker niet ondertekenen' are fine.